# spring 5 - Oauth2 server get current user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have build a Spring boot oauth2 server using spring 5. The oauth server works and I can login using basic auth and username/password. I get a bearer token and I can verify the token using the /oauth/check_token url.

In the same Spring boot project I want to add an endpoint that will print out the authenticated user information so that oauth2 clients can get information over the logged in user. I created an endpoint /user and it looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
@ResponseBody
public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
}
```

I startup postman so that I can do the api calls and such, call /oauth/token and I receive a token. I then start a new request, set the authentication method to bearer token and fill in the received bearer token. I do a GET call to the url (http://localhost:8080/user) and it turns out the principal is always null. I know because I can debug my application in Spring tool suite and Principal is always empty. I have also tried:

```
OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication)SecurityContextHolder.getContext() .getAuthentication();
```

That is empty as well. How can I create an endpoint that will print the user info so that clients can set the userInfoUri property.

Comment: could you please share you full request details to /users.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer. I'll post it here just in case someone else runs into this problem.

I have a ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter with the following configure in it:

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous()
        .disable()
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/api/user/**").and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
        // More rules here
```

The reason it didn't work because of the first antMatchers("/api/user/**"). I changed it into this:

```
http.anonymous()
    .disable()
    .requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("**").and().authorizeRequests()
```

I believe that the first antMatchers determines the path in which it forces authorizeRequests (Enabling oauth2 security in that path) so if the first path is .antMatchers("/api/user/**") after that is .antMatchers("/user") then it won't match and the /user url won't have the oauth2 security enabled.